# Get all properties and related ID of an item using SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

I want to retrieve all properties and their ID of one item from Wikidata by using SPARQL. I have two queries.

This query only can retrieve properties without their IDs:

[image]

The result of it is shown like this:

[image: result]

This query only can retrieve two-level properties with ID:

[image]

And this is the result:

[image: result]

Is there any way to mix them to show all properties with their IDs?

Comment: this is the first time I post questions. I have no idea why the picture doesn't show. please click the link to see the picture. ty

Comment: I don't get it, what is wrong with your second query and the result? The only thing your query is missing are the values which are literals and therefore won't have a label. In that regards, put the `rdfs:label` pattern into an `OPTIONAL` clause or just use the Wikidata label service

Comment: Instead of embedding screenshots of the queries, please [edit] your question and include the query as actual text (using [code markup](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)).

Comment: What I wanna do is to get the wdpqLabel and pq_Label in the second query like the first query do. Also, I wanna the IDs of each label in the second query.

Comment: still not sure if I understand your problem, you can just select more variables in your first query if you also want the IDs: `SELECT ?wd ?wdLabel ?ps_ ?ps_Label ?wdpq ?wdpqLabel ?pq_ ?pq_Label {`